# stripe handlecardsetup is not a function in react native?

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I am regularly getting a notice for stripe security updates so i need to update stripe generate token function according to stripe requirement which is following url:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration/automatic-confirmation#saving-cards

I checked everything but nothing get helped for updating my cartToken function to handleCardSetup method.

If anyone having an idea for the same please let me know for now I am using

```
react-native-stripe-api
```

Comment: did you update your API version in your dashboard?

Comment: It does not look like that method is supported in https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-stripe-api, which hasn't been updated for quite some time? 

If you want a more actively maintained react native lib, perhaps look at https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe --- they are migrating it for SCA!

Comment: Yes, I checked it and we need to wait for 1 Sep.